# Google Maps info window issue

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Hi I have adapted code from examples and other websites to suit myself, I need the info window to display four attributes, "name" "address" "phone" and "breeds". Once I remove `var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");` (which is an existing attribute from the google maps example code)

and replace it with:

```js
var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
var breeds = markers[i].getAttribute("breeds");
```

The map doesn't display any markers. I am not that high up on javascript so its probably something simple I'm missing. The map can be found here: http://connormccarra.com/test/.

The info is being taken from this xml file: http://connormccarra.com/test/phpsqlajax_genxml3.php

```js
function load() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5076512854544, -7.701416015625),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


    // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
    downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
            });
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
    });
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: But I can see the markers quite well on the latest version of Firefox. What browser are you using?

Comment: I can see the markers also, but what I want is to have name,address,phone and breeds info showing in the info window when you click on the marker. Anytime  I try to change that the markers disappear, obviously I'm not doing the coding right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the problem:

```
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
```

The code you copied is is setup to change the icon based on the "type".  If you remove the line:

```
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
```

There should be a clear javascript error.  If you don't want the custom icons, change that line to var icon = {};  or remove it and change your marker to be:

```
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point
      });
```

Comment: Cheers! Knew it was something simple.